# How to share backend types with Vite (Preact-ts template)?

Tags: typescript, types, mapping, vite, preact

I would like to access my types from backend (Express.js) in my vite app. I cannot get it to work properly.

Could you please point me in the right direction so I can easily share types between frontend and backend?

Here is how I want my types to be exported from **backend**:

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAUvX.png)

*types/test/test-entity.ts*

```
export interface TestInterface {
    test: string;
    test2: number;
};

export interface TestInterface2 {
    test: string;
    test2: number; 
}
```

*types/test/index.ts*

```
export * from './test-entity';
```

*types/index.ts*

```
export * from './test'
```

And now my **frontend** (Vite Preact-ts) configuration:

*./tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
       "types": ["../backend/types"], 
    },
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Now, when I want to import this interface on frontend side like so:

```
import {TestInterface} from 'types';
const a: TestInterface = 'sd'
```

It does not work.

Comment: are your front/server same package and tscofig?

Comment: Different package with its own tsconfig.

Comment: If it's a different package you should make it a peer/optional dependency in package.json and `import type {MyType} from '@me/my-package'`. See `yarn workspaces` or `pnpm workspaces` or whatever yout npm is